# Override standart Spring Data REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have one Entity `User` in my app. Spring Data REST provides me standard endpoints:

```
`GET`    /user
`GET`    /user/<id>
`POST`   /user
`PUT`    /user
`PATCH`  /user
`DELETE` /user/<id>
```

I need to override default behaviour of `DELETE` endpoint not changing endpoint url `/user`. If I add following to my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class User {

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") final String id) {
        userService.delete(id); // in service I remove user with other 
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    // other custom endpoints

}
```

I found that other standard REST endpoints do not work - I always receive 405 error. So, my question is - how to customize this endpoint and not affect other endpoints? (I know how to do this in `@RepositoryEventHandler` - but I should avoid this in my case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read this: [Overriding Spring Data REST Response Handlers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers)?

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/users") // or 'user'? - check this...
public class UserController {

    @Autoware 
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Transactional 
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}") 
    public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable("id") String id) { // or Long id?..

        // custom logic

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

But if you want to add extra business logic to delete process you even don't need to implement a custom controller, you can use a custom [event handler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_writing_an_annotated_handler):

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class) 
public class UserEventHandler {

  @Autoware 
  private UserRepo userRepo;

  @BeforeDeleteEvent
  public void beforeDelete(User u) {
    //...
    if (/* smth. wrong */) throw new MyException(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but how to do this in Controller?

Comment: @Серг0 that's what I'm looking for! Дякую